# How to prevent compositing with an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, webgl

I am developing an application using a WebGL canvas, and I notice through benchmarking that a significant amount of time is spent "compositing layers".

But I don't *think* this should be occurring, because my entire HTML page only has a single element (the canvas).

What I think is happening is that it's blending the background color of the HTML page with the contents that are drawn to the canvas. This seems to be the case since when I change the background color of my HTML page, elements in my scene drawn onto the canvas appear lighter or darker.

Is there a way to disable this compositing? I do not want to blend the background color of my page with what is drawn to the canvas. In doing so I hope not only will the entire "compositing" operation be removed (and performance saved), but also the contents of my canvas will no longer be blended with my page's background.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

gl.clearColor(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1);

function render() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Here's an example above. If you run this code and profile it, you'll notice a significant "Composite Layers" section in the results:

[image]

But I do not wish to composite with the background. Rather than blending with it, I want it to simply be pasted on top. Is there any way to remove this costly process?

Comment: Canvas contents should not be mixed with the background unless your canvas has an opacity less than 100%?

Comment: My canvas has a normal opacity, and mixing seems to occur anyway, for whatever reason.

Comment: Is this just a WebGL thing or is using the 2D context also causing this?

Comment: I have no idea if a 2D canvas also causes this problem. I assume so?

Comment: give some runnable codes here to debug so everyone can see and fix it

Comment: Yeah, one second. I'll try to whip up an example.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I don't understand the reason for invoking JS every frame (rquestAnimationFrame). Could you describe what the purpose of that is (given nothing seems to be changing).

Comment: It's just an example. But games paint like that so it's common

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the WebGL context, if you don't explicitly request the context to *not* have alpha, you get alpha, and the compositor will have to at least examine each pixel to determine if it needs blending with the page.

From section 5.2.1 of the WebGL standard:

> alpha
>
> If the value is true, the drawing buffer has an alpha channel for the purposes of performing OpenGL destination alpha operations and compositing with the page. If the value is false, no alpha buffer is available.

Try creating the context with "alpha:false":

```
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2",  { alpha: false } );
```

Comment: Oh cool this fixed it. There's still an expensive "Composite Layers" section in the profiler, but I think that might just be the term the browser uses for drawing it to the screen, so it's impossible to get rid of. This prevents the alpha bleeding though, so thanks!